# properly formatting an information-friendly URL

Tags: seo, url

I have a problem with formatting a URL to make SEO tools happy with it.

I currently have a URL similar to this:

```
https://www.example.com/Toronto_The-Flatiron_M5E-1C9/February-16-2024_600pm_ages36-49/
```

Many people complain about the underscores in the URL and believe they equal nothing when google scans the URL.

So then I tried this:

```
https://www.example.com/Toronto/The-Flatiron/M5E-1C9/February-16-2024/600pm/ages36-49/
```

But one tool claimed the directory level is too deep.

I would have an easier time if no information required spaces.

Here is the information I need to have in the URL so people can find the event easily:

City
Name of venue
Postal Code
Date
Start time
age group

What do I replace the underscores with to make the URL SEO friendly and to make the URL still make some sort of sense to the reader?

Comment: Hyphens are fine and recommended to replace spaces by Google: [URL structure best practices for Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/url-structure#:~:text=Consider%20using%20hyphens%20to%20separate,(%20_%20)%20in%20your%20URLs). Tools are not always accurate, it sounds like that one might be interpreting the hyphens as directories.

Comment: The one tool interpreted the slashes as directory separators. I understand your thing with hyphens but I'm trying to figure out if I should replace the underscores and with what character(s) instead while still trying to make the URL make sense to the reader.

Comment: That's really a [subjective opinion](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) in terms of what might sense to your readers, but Google recommends using hyphens in replace of spaces, using anything else like `+` would just be more confusing. The URL you tried looks fine, and would likely be understood by both the Googlebot for indexing and by readers (who in most cases don't often look at URLs). In terms of the SEO tool stating "directory level is too deep", search engines really [don't care](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-deep-subfolders-urls-seo-32818.html) about that.